# Batch move many .tif files from their directories to respective subdirectories (all named “R20m”)

Tags: loops, recursion, cmd, move

I am trying to move many .tif images in a batch file. I have a lot of folders with subfolders that all have the same folder structure. I one of this folders is one .tif file that always has a similar name (it contains "SCL" in the name). In that folder there is also a subfolder that always has a name "R20m". I want to move all of these .tif images to their respective R20m subfolder. I am stuck with the syntax. This is what I have so far:

```dos
for /r %%g in (*_SCL_*.tif) do Move %%g "%%~dp\R20m"
```

I do not know how to combine the current drive and/or path of the for loop with the R20 folder name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are very close. You just omitted the for loop variable name to be expanded. Does this work?

```
for /r %%g in (*_SCL_*.tif) do Move "%%~g" "%%~dpgR20m\"
```

Check to see that the new directory exists.

```
for /r %%g in (*_SCL_*.tif) do (IF EXIST "%%~dpgR20m\" (Move "%%~g" "%%~dpgR20m\"))
```

Comment: Hmmm, this does move the original file into the subfolder, but it creates from it a file without extension called R20. If I add extension at the end of the code like this:  "%%~dpgR20m.tif", then the file is not moved but only renamed and it stays in the same location. Not sure how can i move it, keep the file name and the extension?

Comment: How about specifying an backslash at the end of the directory it is moving to? See revised answer.

Comment: Excellent, that is the solution I was looking for. Thank you kind sir!